# how to press enter in an input field after set Interval

Tags: javascript

i was just wondering if there is anyway to auto press the enter key in an input field after setInterval auto fills from with string?

```js
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById('hudinput').value = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="hudid" class="hudclass">
  <input type="text" name="hud" id="hudinput" class="hud-input" placeholder="Enter text here..." maxlength="140">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it in a `form` or something? Select the form and submit it, or call whatever handler that's triggered when `enter` is pressed

Comment: Yeah, I have to ask _"why"_? This immediately sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: whats the problem its not working? in post you coded is works fine every 5 sec it changing its value

Answer (score 1):

Pressing enter in the textbox makes no sense to me, so I'm trying to guess what you want.

### Sending a form

If you have something like this:

```
<form method="post" id="theForm">
    <div id="hudid" class="hudclass">
        <input type="text" name="hud" id="hudinput" class="hud-input" placeholder="Enter text here..." maxlength="140">
    </div>
</form>
```

and you want to send this form, just call `document.getElementById("theForm").submit()` in your `setInterval` function.

Since you're using `setInterval`, you may also want to see `ajax`. [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is a good first choice.

### Appending a new line

Are you trying to appending a new line in a textbox? No, `<input type="text">` is not a multiline textbox. You would like to use a `<textarea>`.

And if you want to append a new line, you can just append a new line and focus instead of pressing enter in it.

```js
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById('hudinput').value = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  document.getElementById('hudinput').value += "\n";
  document.getElementById('hudinput').focus();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<textarea id="hudinput" class="hud-input" placeholder="Enter text here..." maxlength="140" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```